# Mangling sk_buff data in a Netfilter module

Tags: networking, netfilter

I am building a module that does massive mangling of the protocol contained within. I am only mangling Layer 4 packets. I convert them back on the other end to how they should be.  The packet size is still 1:1, so there really isn't a need to reallocate skb...

That said, I change `skb->data`, and then return `NF_ACCEPT` from my `NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT` hook. I have another hook that shows me that the sk_buff is passed to `NF_IP_POST_ROUTING`, but the packet never actually leaves the host (as in I don't see it in Wireshark).  I can't figure out what is going on. Is the packet being dropped somewhere? I am not using any other kernel hooks other than the netfilter hooks and I am not manipulating the destination, so it should leave the machine without question.

Any ideas what might be causing it?  Do I need to register my custom IPPROTO with the kernel?  I have it in `/etc/protocols` I figured that would be enough.  Or am I just going down the wrong path entirely?  I tried working with the ESP and AH code that's in the kernel for IPsec, since it also mangles the packets, but all the transform code is more complicated than I need for what I am doing.

Comment: I haven't followed all your post, so just one point: the kernel doesn't even read `/etc/protocols`, and anyway that's only a database that relates names with numbers. That file is irrelevant to any kernel programming.

Comment: I thought that was the case.  The only thing I found that had anything to do with `/etc/protocols` is the `netdb.h` header. I will update my answer later after I get a blog post together with further details of what I and how I did it so that others could learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolution

It would seem I was doing everything correctly with a single exception. I wasn't recalculating the IP header's checksum (since I was changing the protocol id itself, this is mandatory).

#### Code

```
iph->check = 0;
iph->check = ip_fast_csum(iph, iph->ihl);
```

And presto it worked.